# Bitbucket pull request puts a dot when space bar is pressed two times

Tags: markdown, bitbucket.org

In the bitbucket pull request reply box, when I type the space bar two times it puts a dot. I don't know why that happens. Does it follow any particular flavor of markdown? Is there a way to avoid this behavior?
**Things I noted:**
But this happens only when I press two spaces quickly.

Comment: It's a fairly standard typing convenience, along with Capitalising the next letter. It may not be bitbucket it at all, the OS could be doing it.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's interesting I am using a Mac. I opened the `TextEdit` and there also it's the same behavior.

Comment: It's a system-wide pref, answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're on Mac, this is a system setting/pref.
System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Add full stop [period] with double-space

[image]
<sup>Pref location will have changed in Ventura, but should be searchable.</sup>

This should work anywhere that respects the Mac Tooblox.